# Neo4j and Doctrine2 style wrapper

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, neo4j

I have recently been testing with this [Doctrine2 style Neo4j wrapper](https://github.com/lphuberdeau/Neo4j-PHP-OGM).  While never having used Doctrine before, I've been going off of the great examples from the Github page as well as the Doctrine documentation and can't seem to get passed a certain point.  I extracted the Neo4j-PHP-OGM library, downloaded Doctrine2 with Composer and included the EntityManager procedurally (for testing) within `bootstrap.php`.

/bootstrap.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

require __DIR__ . '/lib/HireVoice/Neo4j/Annotation/Entity.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/HireVoice/Neo4j/Annotation/Auto.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/HireVoice/Neo4j/Annotation/Property.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/HireVoice/Neo4j/Annotation/Index.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/HireVoice/Neo4j/Annotation/ManyToOne.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/HireVoice/Neo4j/Annotation/ManyToMany.php';

$em = new HireVoice\Neo4j\EntityManager(array(
     'transport' => 'curl', // or 'stream'
     'host' => 'localhost',
     'port' => 7474,
    // 'username' => null,
    // 'password' => null,
    // 'proxy_dir' => '/tmp',
    // 'debug' => true, // Force proxy regeneration on each request
    // 'annotation_reader' => ... // Should be a cached instance of the doctrine annotation reader in production
));
```

/User.php

```
namespace Entity;

use HireVoice\Neo4j\Annotation as OGM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @OGM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @OGM\Auto
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OGM\Property
     * @OGM\Index
     */
    protected $fullName;

    function setFullName($fullname){
        $this->fullname = $fullname;
    }
}
```

/save.php

```
require 'bootstrap.php';
require 'User.php';

$repo = $em->getRepository('Entity\\User');

$jane = new User;
$jane->setFullName('Jane Doe');

$em->persist($jane);
$em->flush();
```

In production, I will be autoloading the entity classes, for now I'm just requiring them.  When loading `save.php` in the browser, it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in C:\htdocs\neo4j-php\ogm\save.php on line 7
```

I'm not sure why since the `User.php` entity class is being required after `bootstrap.php`.  Any suggestions as to why?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue seems to be related to PHP namespaces more than with the library.

```
require 'bootstrap.php';
require 'User.php'; // Are you certain the path is correct?

$repo = $em->getRepository('Entity\\User');

$jane = new Entity\User; // Need to specify the full class path unless you import it locally
$jane->setFullName('Jane Doe');

$em->persist($jane);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to specify the full class path.